# Onsen UI 2 with Angular JS

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I would like to migrate my app to Onsen2 . 
Currently my app us in onsen UI1. 
What is the best way / process to migrate the app?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here:  https://onsen.io/2/index.html

**Migration from Onsen UI 1.x**

Although Onsen UI 2.0 is no longer AngularJS dependent, we provide AngularJS binding to supplement AnuglarJS cool features. To include ng-* bindings, please include “angular-onsenui.js" after loading onsenui.js.

```
<script src="onsenui.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-onsenui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will give it a try and will post my feedback